# Geometric probability with square

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Jhon and Simon have common bank account which has $720$ dollars. Each of them has to buy a gift independently from other (Gift cost $< 360$ dol). What is the probability that after shopping there is $\geq 190$ dollars in the bank account left?

**My solution:**

[image: My solution]

Green color is what we need and then $$P= \frac{360 \cdot 360 - \frac{190 \cdot 190}{2}}{360 \cdot 360} \approx 0.86072$$

*What do you think about my solution?*

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Assuming that the cost of each gift is a uniform random variable between 0 and 360, I think you're correct. Furthermore, just for kicks, I ran a quick Mathematica script simulating this with $n=10^6$ samples, and obtain $P = 0.861087$, so there you have it.